# writing json string to elasticsearch from python mapping error

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a json string and write it to es as a document but im getting a mapping error. I used type json and followed the api guide for doing it with the elasticsearch python module linked below.

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html

Here is my code for creating my index, and writing the document. I'm not including the id because the id field in es should auto increment:

```
def create_es_index(es, index):
    es.indices.create(index=index, ignore=400)

def write_to_es(es, index, doc, doc_type):
    res = es.index(index=index, doc_type=doc_type, body=doc)
    es.indices.refresh(index=index)
    return res['created']
```

json string

```
{"instance_id": "MyMac", "timestamp": "2016-03-03 23:03:47.507281", "metrics": {"net_connections": {}, "disk_usage": {"/dev/disk1": {"disk_percent": 35.9, "disk_total": 475936.0, "disk_used": 170993.328125, "disk_free": 304692.671875}}, "cpu_usage": {"idle_cpu": 93.1, "user_cpu": 4.1, "cpu_count": 8, "system_cpu": 2.8}, "disk_io": {"disk0": {"write_bytes": 142929.91748046875, "read_count": 805448, "write_count": 1067792, "read_time": 379106, "read_bytes": 131261.80908203125, "write_time": 270700}}, "net_io": {"gif0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 0, "bytes_sent": 0.0, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}, "en2": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 0, "bytes_sent": 0.0, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}, "en0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 2200957, "bytes_sent": 750.8597402572632, "packets_rcv": 2841066, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 1986.7214736938477}, "en1": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 0, "bytes_sent": 0.0, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}, "lo0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 36070, "bytes_sent": 3.0028305053710938, "packets_rcv": 36070, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 3.0028305053710938}, "bridge0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 1, "bytes_sent": 0.0003261566162109375, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}, "p2p0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 0, "bytes_sent": 0.0, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}, "stf0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 0, "bytes_sent": 0.0, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}, "awdl0": {"packet_drop_in": 0, "packet_err_in": 0, "packets_sent": 377, "bytes_sent": 0.0705881118774414, "packets_rcv": 0, "packet_drop_out": 0, "packet_err_out": 0, "bytes_rec": 0.0}}, "running_proccess": {"networkd": {"status": "running", "name": "networkd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867937.140083, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "_networkd"}, "storedownloadd": {"status": "running", "name": "storedownloadd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867977.951888, "memory_percent": 0.015735626220703125, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "iconservicesd": {"status": "running", "name": "iconservicesd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457021564.441307, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "_iconservices"}, "diskarbitrationd": {"status": "running", "name": "diskarbitrationd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.693072, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "askpermissiond": {"status": "running", "name": "askpermissiond", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.333416, "memory_percent": 0.017523765563964844, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057190.230844, "memory_percent": 0.08437633514404297, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "pkd": {"status": "running", "name": "pkd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457021658.691978, "memory_percent": 0.05474090576171875, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "filecoordination": {"status": "running", "name": "filecoordination", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867957.162599, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "Sublime Text 2": {"status": "running", "name": "Sublime Text 2", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456870926.803651, "memory_percent": 0.9954690933227539, "threads": 8, "user": "grantzukel"}, "loginwindow": {"status": "running", "name": "loginwindow", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867936.698557, "memory_percent": 0.08683204650878906, "threads": 2, "user": "root"}, "diagnostics_agent": {"status": "running", "name": "diagnostics_agent", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.335594, "memory_percent": 0.028634071350097656, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "helpd": {"status": "running", "name": "helpd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457037313.97938, "memory_percent": 0.034308433532714844, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "universalAccessAuthWarn": {"status": "running", "name": "universalAccessAuthWarn", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456965430.607015, "memory_percent": 0.058007240295410156, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "cloudphotosd": {"status": "running", "name": "cloudphotosd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057190.585324, "memory_percent": 0.16238689422607422, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "CoreServicesUIAgent": {"status": "running", "name": "CoreServicesUIAgent", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457038139.904283, "memory_percent": 0.09548664093017578, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "networkd_privile": {"status": "running", "name": "networkd_privile", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457008662.006768, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "autofsd": {"status": "running", "name": "autofsd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.696956, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "lsuseractivityd": {"status": "running", "name": "lsuseractivityd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457005767.703641, "memory_percent": 0.05099773406982422, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "accountsd": {"status": "running", "name": "accountsd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457009666.846858, "memory_percent": 0.04749298095703125, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "imagent": {"status": "running", "name": "imagent", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867958.379099, "memory_percent": 0.029540061950683594, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.ifdrea": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.ifdrea", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457057187.998956, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "Slack": {"status": "running", "name": "Slack", "cpu_percent": 0.2, "start_time": 1456867956.892902, "memory_percent": 2.3811817169189453, "threads": 31, "user": "grantzukel"}, "CrashReporterSup": {"status": "running", "name": "CrashReporterSup", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867967.444796, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "Notes": {"status": "running", "name": "Notes", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867956.970217, "memory_percent": 0.10504722595214844, "threads": 11, "user": "grantzukel"}, "syspolicyd": {"status": "running", "name": "syspolicyd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867957.176839, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "airportd": {"status": "running", "name": "airportd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.69126, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "EscrowSecurityAlert": {"status": "running", "name": "EscrowSecurityAlert", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457031351.167674, "memory_percent": 0.10287761688232422, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "crashpad_handler": {"status": "running", "name": "crashpad_handler", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867957.640885, "memory_percent": 0.028634071350097656, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "pboard": {"status": "running", "name": "pboard", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867957.13867, "memory_percent": 0.0010013580322265625, "threads": 1, "user": "grantzukel"}, "pbs": {"status": "running", "name": "pbs", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457011495.380757, "memory_percent": 0.050902366638183594, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "SocialPushAgent": {"status": "running", "name": "SocialPushAgent", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.330223, "memory_percent": 0.016427040100097656, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "storelegacy": {"status": "running", "name": "storelegacy", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867977.531367, "memory_percent": 0.010442733764648438, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.CodeSi": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.CodeSi", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457005904.974333, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "cloudd": {"status": "running", "name": "cloudd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457031350.010078, "memory_percent": 0.0947713851928711, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.CommerceKit.TransactionService": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.CommerceKit.TransactionService", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457039305.782683, "memory_percent": 0.03998279571533203, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "spindump": {"status": "running", "name": "spindump", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456868060.44271, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "coresymbolicatio": {"status": "running", "name": "coresymbolicatio", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457011494.438803, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "fontd": {"status": "running", "name": "fontd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867957.060531, "memory_percent": 0.033926963806152344, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "launchd": {"status": "running", "name": "launchd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.171422, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "photolibraryd": {"status": "running", "name": "photolibraryd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057190.233233, "memory_percent": 0.12862682342529297, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "Microsoft Outlook": {"status": "running", "name": "Microsoft Outlook", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457063462.868187, "memory_percent": 0.5756855010986328, "threads": 17, "user": "grantzukel"}, "GoPro Importer": {"status": "running", "name": "GoPro Importer", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.336018, "memory_percent": 0.04858970642089844, "threads": 13, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.Accoun": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.Accoun", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457015184.055281, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "SandboxedServiceRunner": {"status": "running", "name": "SandboxedServiceRunner", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457038138.405657, "memory_percent": 0.03981590270996094, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "storeassetd": {"status": "running", "name": "storeassetd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867977.583959, "memory_percent": 0.06153583526611328, "threads": 4, "user": "grantzukel"}, "stackshot": {"status": "running", "name": "stackshot", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.698207, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "quicklookd": {"status": "running", "name": "quicklookd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457061567.469845, "memory_percent": 0.06437301635742188, "threads": 4, "user": "grantzukel"}, "NotificationCenter": {"status": "running", "name": "NotificationCenter", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.332244, "memory_percent": 0.13697147369384766, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "securityd_servic": {"status": "running", "name": "securityd_servic", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867956.691489, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "com.apple.Perfor": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.Perfor", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457005772.832286, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "mdworker": {"status": "running", "name": "mdworker", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456891688.549669, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "kenzanadmin"}, "corestoraged": {"status": "running", "name": "corestoraged", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867938.074113, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "AirPlayUIAgent": {"status": "running", "name": "AirPlayUIAgent", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457011430.754611, "memory_percent": 0.0713348388671875, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "Finder": {"status": "running", "name": "Finder", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867957.161853, "memory_percent": 1.3857364654541016, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "LookupViewService": {"status": "running", "name": "LookupViewService", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456869732.242552, "memory_percent": 0.1617908477783203, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "sharingd": {"status": "running", "name": "sharingd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867957.326738, "memory_percent": 0.036978721618652344, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "nsurlsessiond": {"status": "running", "name": "nsurlsessiond", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457031351.200234, "memory_percent": 0.038051605224609375, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "hidd": {"status": "running", "name": "hidd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.699279, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "VDCAssistant": {"status": "running", "name": "VDCAssistant", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867938.075522, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "periodic-wrapper": {"status": "running", "name": "periodic-wrapper", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457026636.841715, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "AppleCameraAssis": {"status": "running", "name": "AppleCameraAssis", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867958.912234, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "com.apple.ctkpcs": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.ctkpcs", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.959475, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "wirelessproxd": {"status": "running", "name": "wirelessproxd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.694852, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "bird": {"status": "running", "name": "bird", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457011564.753462, "memory_percent": 0.07686614990234375, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "ntpd": {"status": "running", "name": "ntpd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456952451.899921, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "Google Chrome Helper": {"status": "running", "name": "Google Chrome Helper", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867959.028873, "memory_percent": 1.2520790100097656, "threads": 5, "user": "grantzukel"}, "deleted": {"status": "running", "name": "deleted", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457021563.315091, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "Keychain Circle Notification": {"status": "running", "name": "Keychain Circle Notification", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.330602, "memory_percent": 0.024247169494628906, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.Ambien": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.Ambien", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867939.296081, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "taskgated": {"status": "running", "name": "taskgated", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.702211, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "mdworker32": {"status": "running", "name": "mdworker32", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457063476.39617, "memory_percent": 0.11932849884033203, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.photomoments": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.photomoments", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057190.584971, "memory_percent": 0.0867605209350586, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457022534.540902, "memory_percent": 0.37822723388671875, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "bash": {"status": "running", "name": "bash", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867959.055111, "memory_percent": 0.0063419342041015625, "threads": 1, "user": "grantzukel"}, "logind": {"status": "running", "name": "logind", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.698742, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "netbiosd": {"status": "running", "name": "netbiosd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457057192.788043, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "_netbios"}, "TISwitcher": {"status": "running", "name": "TISwitcher", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867967.359227, "memory_percent": 0.021147727966308594, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "mdflagwriter": {"status": "running", "name": "mdflagwriter", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867978.363686, "memory_percent": 0.0035762786865234375, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "PKIClientAgent": {"status": "running", "name": "PKIClientAgent", "cpu_percent": 0.1, "start_time": 1456867967.334381, "memory_percent": 0.009822845458984375, "threads": 7, "user": "grantzukel"}, "ocspd": {"status": "running", "name": "ocspd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457046342.663486, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867959.620084, "memory_percent": 0.3336668014526367, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "login": {"status": "running", "name": "login", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867959.016234, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "grantzukel"}, "com.apple.dock.extra": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.dock.extra", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867958.112889, "memory_percent": 0.0400543212890625, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "softwareupdated": {"status": "running", "name": "softwareupdated", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1457026636.842934, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "_softwareupdate"}, "firefox": {"status": "running", "name": "firefox", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456948571.230037, "memory_percent": 4.192876815795898, "threads": 70, "user": "grantzukel"}, "PTPCamera": {"status": "running", "name": "PTPCamera", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057188.012836, "memory_percent": 0.1312255859375, "threads": 7, "user": "grantzukel"}, "CVMServer": {"status": "running", "name": "CVMServer", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867939.25421, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "thermald": {"status": "running", "name": "thermald", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.69007, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "Google Chrome": {"status": "running", "name": "Google Chrome", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867956.856451, "memory_percent": 1.5878677368164062, "threads": 41, "user": "grantzukel"}, "mds_stores": {"status": "running", "name": "mds_stores", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867937.415695, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "VTDecoderXPCService": {"status": "running", "name": "VTDecoderXPCService", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867959.263701, "memory_percent": 0.12454986572265625, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "appleeventsd": {"status": "running", "name": "appleeventsd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.690326, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "_appleevents"}, "soagent": {"status": "running", "name": "soagent", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457005772.710991, "memory_percent": 0.11584758758544922, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "CalNCService": {"status": "running", "name": "CalNCService", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457005805.563086, "memory_percent": 0.12059211730957031, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "watchdogd": {"status": "running", "name": "watchdogd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867947.315118, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "apple.DevicePropertyReader": {"status": "running", "name": "apple.DevicePropertyReader", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057189.054241, "memory_percent": 0.022268295288085938, "threads": 2, "user": "grantzukel"}, "usbmuxd": {"status": "running", "name": "usbmuxd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.695495, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "_usbmuxd"}, "mapspushd": {"status": "running", "name": "mapspushd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457026636.843442, "memory_percent": 0.06449222564697266, "threads": 4, "user": "grantzukel"}, "identityservicesd": {"status": "running", "name": "identityservicesd", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867957.441673, "memory_percent": 0.040912628173828125, "threads": 3, "user": "grantzukel"}, "revisiond": {"status": "running", "name": "revisiond", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.698371, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "com.apple.geod": {"status": "running", "name": "com.apple.geod", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1457057190.73462, "memory_percent": 0.05383491516113281, "threads": 5, "user": "grantzukel"}, "authd": {"status": "running", "name": "authd", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867936.828017, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "TMCacheDelete": {"status": "running", "name": "TMCacheDelete", "cpu_percent": "null", "start_time": 1456867957.261204, "memory_percent": "null", "threads": "null", "user": "root"}, "SpotlightNetHelper": {"status": "running", "name": "SpotlightNetHelper", "cpu_percent": 0.0, "start_time": 1456867960.156749, "memory_percent": 0.049042701721191406, "threads": 5, "user": "grantzukel"},
```

trimmed for space

main code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': '127.0.0.1'}])

    index = "sherlock"

    create_es_index(es, index)

    while True:

        insert_document = build_doc_for_insertion()
        json_conversion = json.dumps(insert_document)
        write_to_es(es, index, json_conversion, "json")

        time.sleep(60)
```

error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2283, in <module>
        globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
      File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.1.0.201505270003/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1709, in run
        pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
      File "/Users/grantzukel/Documents/WorkScripts/PythonScripts/ami-provisioning/roles/sherlock/files/opt/reuters/system-apps/sherlock.py", line 622, in <module>
        write_to_es(es, index, json_conversion, "json")
      File "/Users/grantzukel/Documents/WorkScripts/PythonScripts/ami-provisioning/roles/sherlock/files/opt/reuters/system-apps/sherlock.py", line 60, in write_to_es
        res = es.index(index=index, doc_type=doc_type, body=doc)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
        return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 254, in index
        _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
        status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 89, in perform_request
        self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
        raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
    elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception')
```

Elasticsearch LOGS

```
[2016-03-04 04:06:54,248][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /sherlock/json Params: {index=sherlock, type=json}
RemoteTransportException[[i-dc592f1b][10.10.199.41:9300][indices:data/write/index]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[i-dc592f1b][ip-10-10-199-41.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.10.199.41:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Field name [apple.DevicePropertyReader] cannot contain '.'];
Caused by: RemoteTransportException[[i-dc592f1b][ip-10-10-199-41.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.10.199.41:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Field name [apple.DevicePropertyReader] cannot contain '.'];
Caused by: MapperParsingException[Field name [apple.DevicePropertyReader] cannot contain '.']
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:276)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:196)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:196)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.RootObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(RootObjectMapper.java:138)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:435)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:257)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:458)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:762)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you also share the errors you get in the ES log?

Comment: @Val yea one second I'll post it up.